# Join multiple tables and result multiple records

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with information.

Table1: Orders

```
+---------+----------------+------------+---------------+
| OrderID | OrderDate      | Community   | Status       |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
 1        | 1 march 2013   | S1          | Approved
 2        | 5 march 2013   | S2          | Aporoved
 3        | 7 march 2013   | Z1          | Approved
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table2: OrderArtickles

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Ordertitem  | OrderID     | ArtikelID   | UnitPrice    | Delivered |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1          | 1           | 20          | 5            | yes
| 2          | 1           | 20          | 5            | yes
| 3          | 2           | 21          | 10           | yes
| 4          | 3           | 30          | 50           | yes
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table3: users

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Userid     | Username   | Community     | Department |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 1          | User1      | S1            | S
| 2          | User2      | S2            | S
| 3          | User3      | Z1            | Z
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

I need a MySQL query that give the following output:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Department     | TotalPriceOfArtikels 
+--------------------------------------+
| S              | 20                   
| Z              | 50                   
+--------------------------------------+
```

I tried with JOIN, SUM, GROUP BY but without result. The problem that I have is that the one order gives multiple articles. Who can help me?

Comment: thanks sergey you fixed my eyes :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    select Department  , sum(UnitPrice) as TotalPriceOfArtikels 
    from users u
    inner join Orders o
    on o.Community = u.Community
    inner join OrderArtickles oa
    on oa.OrderId = o.OrderId
    group by Department
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4a10/2)

OUTPUT:

```
    Department  TotalPriceOfArtikels
        S             20
        Z             50
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The query is working but the sum of the price is not correct. When I run the query on the database, the price too high.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select us.Department,
sum ( art.UnitPrice ) as TotalPriceOfArtikels
from user us
 left join orders ors
on ( us.Community = ors.Community)
 left join OrderArtickles art
on ( ors.OrderID = art.OrderID)
group by us.Department
```

------------------EDITED------------------------

I copy the same values and structures of your tables in my mysql, and the result is fine, it give me:

```
Department  TotalPriceOfArtikels
    S             20
    Z             50
```

Maybe you want to check a condition, like if delivered = yes or status = aprobed??....with this query the result it's the same that you have posted ;)

Saludos ;)

Comment: You're missing `SUM()` -- typo?

Comment: Thanks for the response, the same issue as the query of "Echo_me". The sum is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tests. I will check it in a few days what the difference is between this demo and the real database.

Comment: The query is working. I found the issue in the production database. There are duplicated users in the Users database. Thanks!!

Comment: The problem is in the data....a classic of classics....feel free to ask whenever you want. You are welcome ;)